# How to warm up canned beans?

Tags: beans

A [recipe](https://www.cookingclassy.com/roasted-veggie-black-bean-tacos/) is asking for "canned black beans, drained, rinsed and warmed".

I've never just heated up beans by themselves. How do I warm up these beans without using a microwave? Do I heat them up in a pan with some butter/oil or in simmering water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a microwave but you've ruled that out. Taking "warmed" literally as meaning made warm but not hot, you could put them in a bowl, cover with boiling water and wait a few minutes. I suspect that you actually want them hot, in which case you could put them in a small pan, pour over boiling water, cover, and return to the boil for a few minutes. If you don't have an electric kettle, just boil a small pan of water and tip the beans in.

Comment: This would help with the rinsing too.

Answer (score 2):

Pour the can into a small pot (without draining or rinsing), and heat on the stove over medium-low heat with a lid on, stirring/shaking frequently.

This is pretty common, even for just heating beans to be eaten. Such as black beans on the side of some tacos or something.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different approaches I might take:

1. Reverse the order of the instructions. Tip the beans and whatever liquid they come in into a pan and warm them gently on the stove top. Then *when warm* drain and rinse.

or

2. Drain and rinse the cold beans and stir them into the roasting vegetables for the last ten minutes of their time in the oven.

Answer (score 0):

Drain, rinse, place in pan on hilltop or microwave.  Add small amount of low sodium chicken broth.  Works great with canned, drained green beans.

Comment: Umm, I think the question is about beans as in “ripe seeds”, not beans as in “unripe seed pods”? Could you please check and [edit] your post to clarify?

Answer (score -2):

Done two days ago. Open, drain, plunge beans in hot water, drain again.

Comment: Why the down vote? Perhaps because is a duplicate of the accepted one? Sometimes people around have surprising behaviour.